# How do we prove that all intervals contained in [0,1] is a semi-algebra?

Tags: semialgebras

Well, I know the definition of semi-algebra but I cannot prove that all intervals contained in [0,1] is a semi-algebra

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi. Do you know the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Many of us probably do.  But we're not here to feed people homework answers.  That's why we want to see evidence that you've tried in good faith to solve the problem before coming here.